# Allow multiple users to simultaneously access different Virtual Machines created in Virtual Box installed in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vnc

I want to setup a Ubuntu Virtual Box having different Windows version, and allow multiple users to remotely access the desired window machine from their own Ubuntu Installation simultaneously.

I've installed Virtual Box, created a Windows 7 Machine, but how I'm supposed to access remotely i.e VNC.??
What server I've to setup?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Windows 7 (i.e., Professional or above), you can enable Remote Desktop Services, and then simply forward port 3389 from the host to the guest; this will enable your users to connect directly to the VM with a Microsoft Terminal Services client (on Windows, `mstsc`; on Linux, `tsclient` or Remmina; on OS X, Microsoft's Remote Desktop client), without needing to open a VNC or other connection to the Ubuntu host first.